# Metadata is uploaded into Blob when uploading Email attachments

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created a logic app to get an email attachment (this is in .csv format) and upload the attachment into a blob container.
However, its uploading the metadata and not the readable data of email attachment.

[image]

Upload properties, it uses Get Attachment Body

[image]

Uploaded csv file to blob
[image]

Any leads to get the uploaded csv file in readable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without the Get attachments step. And use Attachments Content for Blob Content.

[image]